# Как в WP вывести все содержимое?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, веб-программирование

Добрый вечер!

У меня есть страница с медицинскими сервисами ([страница](http://centurymedicaldental.com/medical-service-items/)). На странице выводиться по 10 сервисов. Как вывести не 10, а все?

Код страницы:
`

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php gg_page_container(); ?>">

            <?php if (have_posts()) :
            // Queue the first post.
            the_post();
            // Rewind the loop back
            rewind_posts();
            ?>
            <div class="gg_posts_grid">
                <ul class="el-grid no_magnific" data-layout-mode="fitRows" data-gap="gap">
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <li class="isotope-item col-md-12">
                        <?php
                            set_query_var( 'medical_services_thumb', 'medical-services-thumb-1col' );
                            get_template_part( 'parts/medical-services/part','medical-service' );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <?php 
            if (function_exists("gg_pagination")) {
                gg_pagination();
            } 
            ?>

            <?php // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            else :
                get_template_part( 'parts/post-formats/part', 'none' );
            endif;
            ?>

            </div>
            <?php gg_page_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->    
</section>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Это код шаблона `archives.php`, если я правильно понимаю. Тогда вместо `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>` попробуйте использовать

`<?php 
query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=100');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>`

где `100` - количество выводимых постов. Выводить все посты - `-1`.

**Обратите внимание.** Этот способ будет работать для всех страниц категорий. Чтобы использовать его только для одной категории, необходимо изменение кода.

Comment: так страница перестает работал: <?php 
                    query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=100');
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    ?>

Comment: ошибка 500. Также я пробовал с -1 и закрывал иф <?php endif; ?>

Comment: <ul class="el-grid no_magnific" data-layout-mode="fitRows" data-gap="gap">  <?php 
                    query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=100');
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    ?>
....
                   <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>

Comment: Странно. К сожалению, больше ничем помочь не могу. Гуглите отключение пагинации WordPress, либо, если используете тему из каталога WordPress - в ней может быть настройка количества выводимых постов

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов, `wp_reset_query();` забыли. Поэтому валилась пятисотая ошибка скорее всего

Answer (score 0):

Простейший способ изменить количество выводимых на страницах блога записей - изменить это число в настройках админ-панели: `Настройки` => `Чтение` => `На страницах блога отображать не более` указываете необходимое вам количество.

Или изменить параметры запроса примерно таким образом:

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="<?php gg_page_container(); ?>">
                <?php
                $args = $query_string . '&posts_per_page=-1';
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="gg_posts_grid">
                        <ul class="el-grid no_magnific" data-layout-mode="fitRows" data-gap="gap">
                            <?php
                            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                                $query->the_post();
                                ?>
                                <li class="isotope-item col-md-12">
                                    <?php
                                    set_query_var('medical_services_thumb', 'medical-services-thumb-1col');
                                    get_template_part('parts/medical-services/part', 'medical-service');
                                    ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    if (function_exists("gg_pagination")) {
                        gg_pagination();
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                } else {
                    get_template_part('parts/post-formats/part', 'none');
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

            </div>
            <?php gg_page_sidebar(); ?>
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</section>
```